# No smart card logon option in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-domain, smartcard

I'm not IT trained but I was tasked to implement smart card windows logon for a particular system. The system has a single server (functions as AD and DC) and many client PCs. All the machines are in the same domain. I've done all the necessary configurations on the server, generated the user certificates and loaded the certificates onto the smart cards. It worked fine for a handful of users, whose workstations are running on Windows 7.

However, I have a user whose workstation is running on Windows 10. I'm able to manage the certificates of the smart card via middleware ActivClient (which means Windows is able to communicate with the card), but I do not see the smart card option/icon at the log on screen. The "sign-in option" button is also missing. How do I show the smart card icon?

Comment: If you have a single workstation that is different from other workstations why don’t you simply reimage the workstation?

Comment: @Ramhound Does that mean there is no direct solution to this? Anyway, I don't have the original Windows 10 image and it was done by someone else, and it doesn't guarantee that it would solve the problem. If you meant to reimage to Windows 7, then it wouldn't make sense to switch to one which is already end-of-support

Comment: How are you suppose to image new machines if you don't have the image that was used? Just because you installed ActivClient does not mean you can use a SmartCard to access the Windows user account.  Technically speaking ActivClient isn't necessary to use SmartCode authentication on Windows 8+ it was only required on Windows 7 since no native support existed for SmartCards.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your reply. Sadly, with the current setup, we would have to configure from scratch. ActivClient was used only to load the certificate into the card - which indicates the driver is correctly installed. If Windows is able to detect and reader and read the card, I don't understand why the smart card logon option isn't present.

Comment: @Jal - Because ActivClient isn’t what provides that authentication method.  I can install ActivClient on my personal machine, but still use my SmartCard, on websites that use that card for authentication.

Comment: What’s the value of *Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>System>Logon*,  if it’s not, {8FD7E19C-3BF7-489B-A72C-846AB3678C96} it probably should be (Windows 10 clients)

Comment: [This](https://help.duo.com/s/article/4987?language=en_US) will explain what’s going on partially.  Cannot help with Windows 7 as it’s over a year out of support.

Comment: You should also configure *Interactive logon: Require smart card*